# How do I display the contents of a text file in a WPF TextBox while retaining the formatting?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, text-files

What i want to do, is get the content of a *.Txt file, into a textbox, and if possible retain the formatting.

now, i found this site here: http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2008/03/02/load-a-txt-file-in-a-textbox.aspx
That discribes an option 2 where you just add a .txt resources file, and read that to the textbox like this:

`txtDisclaimer.Text = Resources.Common.disclaimer_en;`

But within my WPF application, the `Resources.Common` part does not exist, and thus not work.
Anyone have a clue how it should be done in WPF?
Or can tell me a better way of getting text file content to a textbox ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply do

`txtDisclaimer.Text = File.ReadAllText("Path of your File");`

To keep the formatting use the overload

`File.ReadAllText Method (String, Encoding)`

Comment: what happens with that, is that the special caracters (like © )get displayed as an ? (dont know if that would be different if i would have read it from resource though)

Comment: Try this one File.ReadAllText Method (String, Encoding). Specify the encoding type of your file. I guess it should work